# Change tag name in XML

Tags: java, xml

I have exception like this:

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"tax"). Expected elements are <{}TaxGroup>
```

I have resposne which is String and look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<tax xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <xml_message_type>tax</xml_message_type>
    <version>
        <xml_version>1.0</xml_version>
    </version>
</tax>
```

How to iterate over this XML and repleace tag name `tax` with `TaxGroup` ?

Comment: What makes you think it would then be acceptable? Does TaxGroup have xml_message_type and version/xml_version child elements, and does the xml_message_type text need to change to 'TagGroup'? It might also be that you have a valid response, and should be looking at how to customise the binding that response to your data rather than changing the response itself.

Answer (score 1):

It must mean that you try to unmarshal your XML which has a root element `<tax>` to Java Jaxb class which expects root element `<TaxGroup>` instead.

Definitelly XML does not match what unmarshaler was requested.

check what Java class do you expect to get out of this XML, and change it accordingly. Also check what element name defined in its JAXB annotation.